# character mapping in edittext android

Tags: android

I want to make my edittext like when I write character "g" it's related mapping custom character should written like here in Hindi it's "जी"

I think there should be character mapping but having no knowledge can anybody help me
how to do that

Other app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nichetech.hindi.editor is also doing same like this way, there is option available offline and online

Online is doing with help of google translator but if I choose Offline then writing happen like this way

Here you can see that Keyboard is English, but writing is done in Hindi language

[image]

Thanks

Is there way that I write in English and it's related mapping character will written in EditText of my application only.

Does anybody done like this way then please help me, how to do that

Comment: if i understand well, then you can make Map for keyboard letters and target letters, then override onKeyUp() or onKeyDown() and replacce character on the editText.... check this https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To accomplish what you're after, I would create a HashMap of chars that map to other chars. If some specific char is not mapped just print it out. Here's an example I've put up:

```
final HashMap<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
charMap.put('q', '1');
charMap.put('w', '2');
charMap.put('e', '3');
charMap.put('r', '4');
charMap.put('t', '5');
charMap.put('y', '6');

final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    boolean replaced;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.e("TAG", start + " " + before + " " + count);
        // Check in lower case
        String oldStr = s.toString().toLowerCase();
        StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder(s);

        // Loop through changed chars
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // Replace if a substitution is avaiable
            Character replacement = charMap.get(oldStr.charAt(start + i));
            if (replacement != null) {
                replaced = true;
                newStr.setCharAt(start + i, replacement);
            }
        }

        if (replaced) {
            replaced = false;
            editText.setText(newStr);
            // Move cursor after the new chars
            editText.setSelection(start + count);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

*Pros:*

- Ignores case when looking for a replacement. (q = Q = 1)
- Replaces immediately single and multiple chars
- Doesn't loop the whole string
- Can replace in the middle of another string

*Cons:*

- You have to have a HashMap entry for every character you want replaced
- ...

---

As a side-note I'd like to name a few limitations that your given app's "online version" has:

- The converting is done only when a space, new line or punctuation mark is entered.
- You cannot add letters to already converted words.

The apps "offline" version also has a minor bug:

- It doesn't convert words that are copied in or written with Swipe

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply but I am talking about OFFLINE Mode, in Offline mode there character is coonverting at the same time when i type, it not about space

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit The app you've given doesn't work in offline mode at all. However my example will work regardless of the internet connection.

Comment: Hi There is slider menu in that you will choose first offline and after that you can do it, it is working fine on my phone, but not in genymotion

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit I see. So what's wrong with my example?

Comment: Here's a [visual proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mfsgL.gif)  that the code works.

Comment: Is it possible to do char replacement as you type with SearchView instead of EditText? It has a similar listener but the onQueryTextChange() method only gives you the current query, not the start, count, etc.

Comment: @irvanjit Google `"searchview get edittext"` and apply the solution on that.

Comment: Tried using it directly on the searchView, (used setQuery() instead) and it works pretty well even without the extra information, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are better off looking at creating your own *.ttf file with all character mappings. You can just set it on your EditText (or whatever text widget you are using). TTF fonts are welcome in assets/ directory (or any directory you can read from). You can create Typeface object with:

`Typeface.createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path)`

and setting it with:

```
textView.setTypeface(mTypeface);
```

Answer (score 0):

Key character map files (.kcm files) are responsible for mapping combinations of Android key codes with modifiers to Unicode characters.Device-specific key layout files are required for all internal (built-in) input devices that have keys, if only to tell the system that the device is special purpose only (not a full keyboard).

Device-specific key layout files are optional for external keyboards, and often aren't needed at all. The system provides a generic key character map that is suitable for many external keyboards.

If no device-specific key layout file is available, then the system will choose a default instead.

Key character map files are located by USB vendor, product (and optionally version) id or by input device name.

Key character map files are located by USB vendor, product (and optionally version) id or by input device name.

Suppose the user pressed A and SHIFT together. The system first locates the set of properties and behaviors associated with KEYCODE_A.

key A {
    label:                              'A'
    base:                               'a'
    shift, capslock:                    'A'
    ctrl, alt, meta:                    none
}

ey ESCAPE {
    base:                               fallback BACK
    alt, meta:                          fallback HOME
    ctrl:                               fallback MENU
}

key A {
    label:                              'A'
    number:                             '2'
    base:                               'a'
    shift, capslock:                    'A'
    alt:                                '#'
    shift+alt, capslock+alt:            none
}

key SPACE {
    label:                              ' '
    number:                             ' '
    base:                               ' '
    shift:                              ' '
    alt:                                '\uef01'
    shift+alt:                          '\uef01'
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MapCharacter() {
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"a", (Object)"\u0905");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"b", (Object)"\u092c");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"c", (Object)"\u091a");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"d", (Object)"\u0926");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"e", (Object)"\u090f");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"f", (Object)"\u092b");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"g", (Object)"\u0917");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"h", (Object)"\u0939");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"i", (Object)"\u0907");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"j", (Object)"\u091c");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"k", (Object)"\u0915");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"l", (Object)"\u0932");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"m", (Object)"\u092e");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"n", (Object)"\u0928");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"o", (Object)"\u0913");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"p", (Object)"\u092a");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"q", (Object)"");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"r", (Object)"\u0930");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"s", (Object)"\u0938");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"t", (Object)"\u0924");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"u", (Object)"\u0909");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"v", (Object)"\u0935");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"w", (Object)"\u0935");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"x", (Object)"\u0915\u094d\u0937");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"y", (Object)"\u092f");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"z", (Object)"\u091d");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"A", (Object)"\u0906");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"B", (Object)"\u092c");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"C", (Object)"\u091a");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"D", (Object)"\u0921");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"E", (Object)"\u090d");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"F", (Object)"\u092b");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"G", (Object)"\u0917");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"H", (Object)"\u0903");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"I", (Object)"\u0908");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"J", (Object)"\u091c");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"K", (Object)"\u0915");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"L", (Object)"\u0933");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"M", (Object)"\u0902");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"N", (Object)"\u0923");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"O", (Object)"\u0911");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"P", (Object)"\u092a");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"Q", (Object)"");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"R", (Object)"\u0930");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"S", (Object)"\u0936");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"T", (Object)"\u091f");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"U", (Object)"\u090a");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"V", (Object)"\u0935");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"W", (Object)"\u0935");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"X", (Object)"\u0915\u094d\u0937");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"Y", (Object)"\u092f");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"Z", (Object)"\u091d");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"1", (Object)"\u0967");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"2", (Object)"\u0968");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"3", (Object)"\u0969");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"4", (Object)"\u096a");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"5", (Object)"\u096b");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"6", (Object)"\u096c");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"7", (Object)"\u096d");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"8", (Object)"\u096e");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"9", (Object)"\u096f");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"0", (Object)"\u0966");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"#", (Object)"\u0953");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"$", (Object)" \u0951");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)"^", (Object)"\u094d");
    this.singleChar.put((Object)":", (Object)"\u0903");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)" ", (Object)" ");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"!", (Object)"!");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"@", (Object)"\u0970");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"%", (Object)"%");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"&", (Object)"\u093d");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"(", (Object)"(");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)")", (Object)")");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"~", (Object)"~");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"`", (Object)"`");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"_", (Object)"_");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"=", (Object)"=");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"{", (Object)"{");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"}", (Object)"}");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"|", (Object)"\u0964");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"\"", (Object)"\"");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"<", (Object)"<");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)">", (Object)">");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"?", (Object)"?");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"+", (Object)"+");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"-", (Object)"-");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"[", (Object)"[");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"]", (Object)"]");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"\\", (Object)"\\");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)";", (Object)";");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"'", (Object)"'");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)",", (Object)",");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)".", (Object)".");
    this.delimtrChar.put((Object)"/", (Object)"/");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"aa", (Object)"\u0906");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"ai", (Object)"\u0910");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"au", (Object)"\u0914");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"ou", (Object)"\u0914");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"ee", (Object)"\u0908");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"oo", (Object)"\u090a");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"aM", (Object)"\u0905\u0902");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"aM~", (Object)"\u0905\u0901");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"aH", (Object)"\u0905\u0903");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"a:", (Object)"\u0905\u0903");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"NG", (Object)"\u0919");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"OM", (Object)"\u0950");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"+~", (Object)"\u5350");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Rs", (Object)"\u20b9");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"||", (Object)"\u0965");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"NY", (Object)"\u091e");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Gy", (Object)"\u091c\u094d\u091e");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"kh", (Object)"\u0916");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"gh", (Object)"\u0918");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Ch", (Object)"\u091b");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"chh", (Object)"\u091b");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"ch", (Object)"\u091a");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"th", (Object)"\u0925");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Th", (Object)"\u0920");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"dh", (Object)"\u0927");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Dh", (Object)"\u0922");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"jh", (Object)"\u091d");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"ph", (Object)"\u092b");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"bh", (Object)"\u092d");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"sh", (Object)"\u0936");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Sh", (Object)"\u0937");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"kSh", (Object)"\u0915\u094d\u0937");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Ri", (Object)"\u090b");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"RI", (Object)"\u0960");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"Li~", (Object)"\u090c");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"LI~", (Object)"\u0961");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"@@", (Object)"\u0971");
    this.doubleChar.put((Object)"$$", (Object)"\u0952");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"a", (Object)"\u093e");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"A", (Object)"\u093e");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"i", (Object)"\u093f");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"I", (Object)"\u0940");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"u", (Object)"\u0941");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"U", (Object)"\u0942");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"e", (Object)"\u0947");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"E", (Object)"\u0945");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"o", (Object)"\u094b");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"O", (Object)"\u0949");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"ai", (Object)"\u0948");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"au", (Object)"\u094c");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"ou", (Object)"\u094c");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"aa", (Object)"\u093e");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"oo", (Object)"\u0942");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"ee", (Object)"\u0940");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"*", (Object)"\u093c");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"M~", (Object)"\u0901");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"r", (Object)"\u094d\u0930");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"R", (Object)"\u0930\u094d");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"Ri", (Object)"\u0943");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"RI", (Object)"\u0944");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"Li~", (Object)"\u0962");
    this.matraChar.put((Object)"LI~", (Object)"\u0963");
}
```