# How to Combine Unicode characters in .kcm file for Physical Keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, unicode, keyboard, unicode-literals, android-custom-keyboard

There are some characters which are not included in Unicode(i.e. `श्र` which is combination of `\u0936 \u094D \u0930`) but can be created using combining sequences. I am unable to figure out how to add this for a Physical Keyboard on Android using '.kcm' file.

**This is a sample of a generic .kcm file**

```
type OVERLAY

key Q {
    label:                              'Q'
    base:                               'q'
    shift, capslock:                    'Q'
}

key W {
    label:                              'W'
    base:                               'w'
    shift, capslock:                    'W'
}
```

**This is what i want, but its not allowed for some reason**

```
key 5 {
    label:                              '5'
    base:                               '\u096b'
    shift:                              '\u091c\u094d\u091e'
}

key 6 {
    label:                              '6'
    base:                               '\u096c'
    shift:                              '\u0924\u094d\u0930'
    alt+shift:                          '\u0302'
}
```

**How do I achieve/map the above letter `श्र`, in this format?**

Comment: Could this be a work around? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718298/character-mapping-in-edittext-android

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I am currently trying out your suggestion. Will revert soon. @bit